# Java calculating invalid results

Tags: java, remote-debugging, netlogo

I am trying to determine the sign of a number to use in a later calculation.

I have code similar to the following:

```
double value = someClass.someGetterMethod();
double sign = value / Math.abs(value);
```

I have also tried:

```
double sign = (value < 0) ? -1d : 1d;
```

Not always, but sometimes value is positive and sign is negative.

Both variables are on the local stack in a non-static method, so I don't believe that there's a race condition.

Unfortunately, I cannot release the full source and I haven't been able to replicate this in a smaller example. I suspect my environment has something to do with it:

The code in question is packaged into a jar, which is then loaded as a zipgroupfileset into a plugin jar file, which is loaded by netLogo as an "extension" (plugin). So NetLogo is launched, which loads the plugin jar that contains the class with this code.

NetLogo requires that any plugins need to be compiled for a 1.5 target, so I have that set for both the lib and the extension in my ant build files.

I connect my netbeans debugger by modifying the netlogo vmargs to allow remote debugging

```
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=1000,server=y,suspend=n
```

I am truly stumped. Is this a problem with how the debugger is displaying the variables? Maybe a problem with NetLogo's 1.5 compilation target requirement?

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Why is sign a double? would an int work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could indeed be a display issue as I don't see how the code in question can have the behaviour you describe.

If I were troubleshooting this, I'd make the variables `final` and would compute `sign` right after `value`:

```
final double value = someClass.someGetterMethod();
final double sign = (value < 0) ? -1d : 1d;
```

Lastly, I'd print out both variables right after the assignment to `sign`. If, having done all this, you can trigger the printing of `value` and `sign` with inconsistent signs, then something is seriously, seriously wrong.

P.S. I would urge you to consider switching to [`Math.signum`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#signum%28double%29). It probably won't fix your current issue, but it'll handle zeroes and NaNs a bit more gracefully.

Comment: both Math.signum and adding final worked. This is a seriously weird problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why making the variables final would make a difference.  I can see why Math.signum would work since it would handle the special cases that arise when working with a double.

Comment: @Kevin: The main reason I suggested `final` was to make sure that some code that we haven't seen didn't modify the variables after they've been computed but before they got inspected.

Comment: I don't know how/why final worked. My breakpoint was right after the line I mentioned and all operations after the fact were read-only. After making it final, there were no errors for modifying a final variable. Something was/is seriously seriously wrong, but at least these workarounds worked.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that should allow you to remove all ambiguity would be to convert the value to the raw long and check the value of the signed bit:

```
long rawValue = Double.doubleToRawLongBits(value);
boolean isNegative = (rawValue & 0x8000000000000000L) != 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is sign a double? would an int work for you?

Your first way of calculating the sign could be prone to rounding errors due to the nature of float/double numbers. I'd say go with the second way:

```
double value = someClass.someGetterMethod();
int  sign = (value < 0) ? -1 : 1;
```

Maybe this will give you better results.

Comment: I don't use an int because the sign variable is used with doubles later on. So if I were to cast or do a manual conversion to an int, I would have to just cast it back afterwards.